Option Strict On disallows late binding & Cannot infer an element type, and Option Strict On does not allow 'Object' to be assumed in vb.net
I have error like this Option Strict On disallows late binding & Cannot infer an element type, and Option Strict On does not allow 'Object' to be assumed in vb.net .
please guide if there is something wrong with my code
Thanks
'Cannot infer an element type, and Option Strict On does not allow 'Object' to be assumed
Dim inputBoxes = {
        BtxtBarcodeIN,
        BtxtcodeproductIN
 }
'Option Strict On disallows late binding 'tb'
            If inputBoxes.Any(Function(tb) tb.Text.Trim().Length = 0) Then
                MessageBox.Show("codeproduct in,Barcode cannot be empty.",
                        "Report Status",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
'Option Strict On disallows late binding 'inputBoxes'
                inputBoxes(0).Select()
                '
                Return ' or Exit Sub 
                BtxtBarcodeIN.Focus()
            End If


Firstly, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That would ALWAYS include the line on which the error is generated. I'm guessing that it's the first line but we shouldn't have to guess or assume.

Assuming that it is the first line, what is the data type of BtxtBarcodeIN and BtxtcodeproductIN. Don't just tell us what type you think they are. Actually use VS to determine what type they are on that line of code. They may well not be what you expect them to be, which would explain the error in the first place. It looks like they maybe supposed to be type TextBox but, if that were the case, I don't see why that line would generate that error.

@jmcilhinney ,
I have updated the line in error code

@jmcilhinney , what is the data type of BtxtBarcodeIN and BtxtcodeproductIN data type of string

Firstly, I doubt that they actually are both type String because, if they were, the first line would not be generating that error message. If they are both type String though, how could the rest of the code possibly work? How could you access .Text, .Select() and .Focus() on a String?

Also, what framework are you targeting and what version of VS are you Using? I tried a few different combinations of data types for those variables and I couldn't get the same error messages as you.

@user23548857 Just to check, does it have Option Infer set to On?

@AndrewMorton, I think it must because that first line gives the following error message with Option Strict On and Option Infer Off: "Option Strict On requires all variable declarations to have an 'As' clause.".

When you resolve the first error, the next two should be resolved as well, because they flow from the compiler failing to infer a type for inputBoxes.  One thing you might do to troubleshoot is, instead of trying to infer the type, declare the type that you think inputBoxes should be.  It may give you a better error message.
